# Please build and install the PortAudio Python bindings first

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pyaudio, portaudio

i already installed pyaudio 
but the problem is when i work with the microphone functions

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
mic = sr.Microphone()
```

the problem is in the third line `mic = sr.Microphone()` 
the terminal will give me this message

```
Please build and install the PortAudio Python bindings first.
```

and if i try to install `pip install PortAudio` it will give me the following message

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PortAudio (from versions: )No matching distribution found for PortAudio
```

so can any one help , it is like i have the pyaudio but the PortAudio is not there !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first uninstall your pyAudio by `pip uninstall pyAudio`

then you need to get the pyAudio compatible with your python version in my case i have 3.7 with 32bit , my problem was trying to install a 64bit pyAudio on my 32bit python .

after the uninstalling i went to this website: [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio)

and i downloaded the [ PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl ]

the way to install it is to go to its directory in the cmd and type `pip install PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl`

and i think this will do and over come the PortAudio problem

Answer (score -1):

Do not type `pip install PortAudio`
There is no such package

You can rather use

```
pip install port audio
```

(lowercase with a space between it).
Happy to Help.