# Speech Recognition in Python PyAudio needs Visual Studio Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, pyaudio

I am Trying to make a Program that uses Speech Recognition (SR), And I know that a popular library for this in Speech Recognition. I download speech recognition with `pip install SpeechRecognition`. I found Out while working on the code I need PyAudio. I tried to install this however it gave me the following error.  `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/`. I have looked for tutorials on how to download this, and I have download it, but it still does not work. Can someone please give me a more detailed explination or point me towards a video on how to install it for python on windows and Add it to the path. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was solved a long time agoo =]] [Why you do not search on google before to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32160102/pyaudio-installtion-error-in-windows)

[Go to this commend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32160102/pyaudio-installtion-error-in-windows#comment52208950_32160141) and click on the link what is there and install it manualy.
The link what you will need to found is something like this:
***people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/packages/….***

Comment: Thanks, but when I run my SR code I get this: Please build and install the PortAudio Python bindings first.. Any Idea on how to do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55202342/please-build-and-install-the-portaudio-python-bindings-first

Answer (score 0):

@andew i also had the same issue but then when i installed it it showed that the debuger is not working so i downeadeed my pthon version by first install th version 3.6.0 from python.org and then is visual studio code i chose the 3.6.0 interpreter and booooom it worked